# Erro ao fazer POST de um json para uma Web API

Tags: c#, json, post, asp.net-web-api

Esta-me a dar um erro quando tento fazer um POST para a API esse erro é:

> System.Net.WebException: O servidor remoto devolveu um erro: (405) Método não permitido.

O código que estou a usar é:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://test-turnoverapi.lyoness.net/");


httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/vnd.lyoness.servicesv1 + json";
httpWebRequest.Date = d2;
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", ": " + hashheader);


using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Entrei");
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

MessageBox.Show(json);
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Entrei");
    var teste = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    MessageBox.Show(teste);
}
```

Gostaria de saber qual é o problema do meu código e como posso resolver o mesmo.

Segue-se um exemplo de um json que a Api fornece :

[image: Segue-se um exemplo de um json que a Api fornece]

Comment: A API possui alguma pagina de documentação? pode postar?

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel só posso postar um exempo de um json que eles têm feito quer ?

Comment: Quanto mais informação, melhor! mas seria interessante alguma documentação.. qual é o site da API?

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel já adicionei uma print com um exemplo que eles fornecem

Comment: @Perozzo Não é a mesma questão

Comment: Talvez seja, visto que está querendo utilizar um serviço REST de forma errada. Leia o link que coloquei e verifique o que está fazendo de errado. O objeto recomendado para ser usado para esse tipo de requisição é um HttpClient.

Comment: `HttpClient` é equivalente ao `WebRequest`

Comment: É equivalente, mas sempre que leio sobre (cursos, tutoriais, etc.), recomedam utilizar HttpClient e não WebRequest.

Comment: @LINQ Mas esta até agora foi a única forma que resultou algo as outras formas todas que testei não mostraram nenhum resultado

Comment: Pedro, o problema é a URL que você está fazendo a requisição.

Comment: @LINQ vou testar outro URL que me é fornecido então.

Comment: Sua API não aceita post ou dua url está errada.
Você pode utilizar o Postmam para testar melhor sua API antes de fazer a implementação do client.

Comment: @LINQ era isso mesmo muito obrigado